# Begriff für "Person, mit der ich mir ein Büro teile"

Tags: single-word-request

Ich suche einen Begriff für eine Person, mit der ich mir das Büro teile.

> Mein Kollege XY, der im selben Büro sitzt wie ich, ist mein ???

Bisher nutze ich [Zimmerkollege](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Zimmerkollege), das ist laut Definition jemand, mit dem man sein Zimmer teilt. Allerdings verbinde ich mit Zimmerkollege eher den Gedanken an ein Mehrbettzimmer bei der Bundeswehr, als an ein Büro.

Habt ihr einen besseren Begriff für mich?

Comment: _Schreibtischnachbar / Schreibtischkollege, Büromitbewohner_?

Comment: Ich glaub, Schreibtischnachbar ist das Wort, das ich suche! @Crissov

Comment: Schreibtischnachbar kann aber auch der Gegenüber in einem Großraumbüro sein. Unter "Büro teilen" verstehe ich eher ein Zwei-Personen-Büro. Ich würde ganz einfach Bürokollege nehmen,

Comment: *Mitinsasse* ;)

Comment: @Crissov: Büros werden i..d.R. nicht bewohnt.

Comment: Ich würde fragen 'Person, mit der ich ein Büro teile', nicht reflexiv 'mir ein Büro teile'. Letzteres würde ich sagen, wenn ich in einem Coworkingspace ein halbes Büro angemietet hätte.

Comment: *Arbeits-* oder *Büroehemann/-frau* – wobei es bei uns auf der Arbeit natürlich entsprechend *Laborehemann/-frau* ist ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ich benutze dafür meist *Büronachbar*, wobei das natürlich auch als *Kollege aus dem benachbarten Büro* missverstanden werden kann.

Analog ließe sich auch der *Schreibtischnachbar* bilden. Da man einen solchen im Allgemeinen nicht teilt, besteht hier nicht die Gefahr eines Missverständnisses.

Comment: Ja, darüber hab ich auch nachgedacht, aber ich würde darunter immer den Kollegen vom Büro nebenan verstehen.

Comment: @Iris Dann ginge vielleicht *Schreibtischnachbar*?

Comment: Mein Favorit ist _Schreibtischnachbar_ (daher nehme ich diese Antwort als richtige Antwort an)

Comment: @Iris: Wenn man ein Büro mit 4 Schreibtischen, von denen jeweils zwei zu einer "Insel" zusammengestellt sind, betrachtet, wäre dann nicht nur der direkte "Nachbar" an der eigenen Insel ein Schreibtischnachbar?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, ich denke nicht. Meine Nachbarn im Mehrfamilienhaus wohnen ja auch über, unter, rechts und links von mir.

Answer (score 3):

Ich kenne hierfür nur den Ausdruck *Bürokollege*, welcher sicherlich nicht selbsterklärend ist - schließlich arbeiten die anderen Kollegen, die in anderen Zimmern platziert sind, genauso mit mir als Kollegen im Büro. Die Bedeutung ergibt sich somit allein daraus, dass man die anderen, "normalen" Kollegen nie als *Bürokollegen* bezeichnet.

Hintergrund: Eigene Erfahrung sowie Kontakt zu Bekannten, alles in einem Umfeld, in dem folgende Merkmale typisch sind:

- Abteilungen, die mehrere Büros umfassen
- relativ kleine Büros mit jeweils 2 - 6 Mitarbeitern
- wenig Sortierung von Kollegen nach Arbeitsaufgaben in Büros, sodass viel büroübergreifender Kontakt stattfindet
- beinahe "freundschaftlicher" Umgang zwischen Kollegen, insbesondere innerhalb eines Büros

In diesem Umfeld tritt die Unterscheidung zwischen Kollegen im selben und in anderen Büros beim Sprechen folglich häufig auf.